# Transform the content-type in apigee

Tags: apigee

Our application needs the request to be application/xml or text/xml.
However sometimes client forget and send without content type specification.

Is it possible to add an apigee policy to add the content-type if not added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to set the content type for all incoming messages.  The easiest way to do this is through an Assign Message policy.  Sample code for setting headers is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="AssignAuthHeaders">
  <DisplayName>AssignAuthHeaders</DisplayName>
  <FaultRules/>
  <Properties/>
  <Add>
    <Headers>
      <Header name="oAuthToken">{access_token}</Header>
      <Header name="appId">{client_id}</Header>
      <Header name="EncryptedHHonorsNumber">{accesstoken.encrypted_hhonors}</Header>
    </Headers>
  </Add>
  <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</AssignMessage>
```

I haven't tried this myself, but you could delete all the Header entries above and put

```html
<Header name="Content-Type">application/xml</Header>
```